# Cocos2d-iphone load large scrollable image like "plant VS zombie"

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How to I load a very large image eg 1024*4608 using cocos2d-iphone and be able to scroll the image?

Answer (score 0):

Your application will be more responsive if you break up your very large image into tiles.  Tiles are smaller images, usually 256 X 256, that can be reassembled by your application into the large image.  You display just the tiles that are visible.  This uses less phone memory.

Here's a **[blog post](http://johnehartzog.com/2009/10/2d-scrolling-game-with-cocos2d-tilemap-with-zoom/)** with some Cocos2D-iPhone image scrolling.